# Установка определённого размера для border

Tags: html, css, css3, border

Подскажите, как можно уменьшить размер бордера, что бы он оканчивался после букви "ш", в слове "Наша".

```css
.title4 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1366px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 60px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1c76bc;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title4">Наша команда</h2>
```

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример 1

```css
.title4 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1366px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.title4:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 85px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #1c76bc;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title4">Наша команда</h2>
```

Пример 2

```css
.title4 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1366px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.title4 span {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1c76bc;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title4"><span>Наш</span>а команда</h2>
```